# Log of sum of sequences converges to maximal limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms

Let
$$
\frac{1}{N}\log(a_N)\to a, \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{N}\log(b_N)\to b
$$
with $a\geq b$. I want to show that
$$
\frac{1}{N}\log(a_N + b_N)\to a
$$
That is, the sequence with maximal limit is dominant.

I already wrote
$$
\frac{1}{N}\log(a_N + b_N) = \frac{1}{N}\log(a_N) + \frac{1}{N}\log\left(1 + \frac{b_N}{a_N}\right)
$$
and am trying to show that the last term converges to $0$ as the first term takes care of the convergence to $a$. I've tried looking if the logarithm converges to a finite constant, so that the division by $N$ makes it $0$, or if if what's inside the logarithm converges to $1$ (that is $\frac{b_N}{a_N}$ converges to $0$).

However, I'm just stuck in a loop of rewriting where the last step of the proof exactly comes down to what there is to prove in the first place. Is this a good approach or can it be done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a_N$ and $b_N$ are positive, here's trick: Subtracting the first two identities gives you $$
\frac{1}{N} \log\left(\frac {a_{N}}{b_N}\right) \rightarrow a - b
$$

Then, for any $0<c<a-b$, we have that for all $N$ sufficiently large \begin{eqnarray}
&\frac{1}{N} \log\left(\frac {a_{N}}{b_N}\right) > c\\
\implies&\frac{a_N}{b_N} > \exp(N c)\\
\implies&\frac{b_N}{a_N} < \exp(-Nc)
\end{eqnarray}

Thus you get $\dfrac{b_N}{a_N}$ goes to $0$.